# Highcharts - Legend Positioning outside the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend, legend-properties

Consider I have highchart like this [highchart with legend inside](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/)

I want legend outside the chart. Please help.

NOTE: I want my legend properties to be the same.

```
legend{
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
}
```

However I want them outside the chart. Please help.

Answer (score 9):

it seems like you need to set 'floating: false' http://jsfiddle.net/hx86zhob/1/

```
legend{
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: false
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. However, toggling 'false' solves the problem here. But doesn't solve the problem in my case :(

Comment: Could you elaborate what is wrong with the example above? How it should look like ?

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. After some tweaking I got my legend to be outside of the chart and show up centered right below it.


_legend: { layout: 'horizontal', align: 'center', verticalAlign: 'bottom', floating: false },_

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
"legend": {
 "align": "left",
  y: -20 // <=== use a negative value 
}
```